# Does selenium / webdriver with protractor wait for async activity in a describe block before continuing?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor

I have code in a desribe block but some of my set up code is outside of the block. That's the code that sets up elements.

When my code executes it runs fine but then I see the browser go to another page before parts of my test have completed. With a different page on the browser then it looks for elements and throws an exception when they are not there.

So how can I handle this problem of the browser going to another page before tests are completed?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of the question you want to be on the same page and don't want to move to the new page which loads when you click on to a link/button. If this is the case then to be on the same page you cane use.

```
Use this command -String oldwindow=window.getWindowHandle();
                 window.switchTo().window(oldwindow);
```

Use this command just below the button code which throws a new window. I am a java programer thats why the code written is in java.
getWindowHandle Methods stores the url of current window in oldwindow string and by using window.switchTo().window(oldwindow) it won't move to new window because you are passing oldwindow as argument for the command.

For more go through the Webdriver documentation by clicking this [link](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#introducing-the-selenium-webdriver-api-by-example)